# Logstash pipeline errors after update from 7.17.9 -> 7.17.10

Tags: logstash, elastic-stack, filebeat, elk

After going through updates earlier this week I noticed that logs were no longer making it to Kibana.  After narrowing it down a bit I think the error is with my logstash server.  Both have the same errors after running for ~30 seconds.

```
[2023-05-11T12:10:07,387][ERROR][logstash.javapipeline    ][main] Pipeline worker error, the pipeline will be stopped {:pipeline_id=>"main", :error=>"(NoMethodError) undefined method `shutdown_requested' for #<LogStash::JavaPipeline:0x60319724>", :exception=>Java::OrgJrubyExceptions::NoMethodError, :backtrace=>["usr.share.logstash.vendor.bundle.jruby.$2_dot_5_dot_0.gems.logstash_minus_output_minus_elasticsearch_minus_11_dot_15_dot_2_minus_java.lib.logstash.plugin_mixins.elasticsearch.common.pipeline_shutdown_requested?(/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/logstash-output-elasticsearch-11.15.2-java/lib/logstash/plugin_mixins/elasticsearch/common.rb:380)", "usr.share.logstash.vendor.bundle.jruby.$2_dot_5_dot_0.gems.logstash_minus_output_minus_elasticsearch_minus_11_dot_15_dot_2_minus_java.lib.logstash.outputs.elasticsearch.wait_for_successful_connection(/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/logstash-output-elasticsearch-11.15.2-java/lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch.rb:440)", "usr.share.logstash.vendor.bundle.jruby.$2_dot_5_dot_0.gems.logstash_minus_output_minus_elasticsearch_minus_11_dot_15_dot_2_minus_java.lib.logstash.outputs.elasticsearch.multi_receive(/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/logstash-output-elasticsearch-11.15.2-java/lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch.rb:390)", "org.logstash.config.ir.compiler.OutputStrategyExt$AbstractOutputStrategyExt.multi_receive(org/logstash/config/ir/compiler/OutputStrategyExt.java:143)", "org.logstash.config.ir.compiler.AbstractOutputDelegatorExt.multi_receive(org/logstash/config/ir/compiler/AbstractOutputDelegatorExt.java:121)", "usr.share.logstash.logstash_minus_core.lib.logstash.java_pipeline.start_workers(/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/java_pipeline.rb:300)"], :thread=>"#<Thread:0x42c34b77 sleep>"}
```

And on my logging servers running filebeat:

```
May 11 06:12:41 logs01.mgmt filebeat[18266]: 2023-05-11T06:12:41.005-0600        ERROR        [publisher_pipeline_output]        pipeline/output.go:154        Failed to connect to failover(backoff(async(tcp://10.0.0.226:5000)),backoff(async(tcp://10.0.0.227:5000))): dial tcp 10.0.0.226:5000: connect: connection refused
May 11 06:12:41 logs01.mgmt filebeat[18266]: 2023-05-11T06:12:41.005-0600        INFO        [publisher_pipeline_output]        pipeline/output.go:145        Attempting to reconnect to failover(backoff(async(tcp://10.0.0.226:5000)),backoff(async(tcp://10.0.0.227:5000))) with 26 reconnect attempt(s)
```

Filebeat config:

```
output.logstash:
  # The Logstash hosts
  hosts: ["10.0.0.226:5000","10.0.0.227:5000"]
```

Logstash config:

```
input {
  beats {
    port => 5000
    type => syslog
  }
}
```

I checked netstat on the logstash machine and it's not even listening on port 5000.  It seems like the server starts and then crashes almost immediately with the pipeline worker error.

I have checked and there is not a firewall running on either end.  SELinux is disabled on both. I have tried restarting logstash and filebeat as root neither seemed to change anything.